# Sqlpredicate query over keys

Tags: predicate, ignite

I am trying to query cache over the keyset of the cache.

Is there a way to apply SqlPredicate over keys of a cache?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignite supports special keywords that allow to work with a cache entry's key and value as with fields. "_key" is the keyword for keys while "_val" is the keyword for values.

The following example shows how you can select data basing on a key value

```
    QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(
    "select _val from Person WHERE _key = 12"));

    List<List<?>> res = cursor.getAll();
```